# Reload component with react hooks

Tags: reactjs

I would like to ask you how to reload a component after modifying the data of a form, then I have my component:

```
export default function MyComponent() {
    const url = "/api/1";
    const [resData, setResData] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const jwt = getJwt();
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const resP = await axios(url);
            setResData(resP.data);
        };
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    return <EditComponent={resData} />
}
```

This component passes my data to the "EditCompoent" child component in which there is a form that is filled with data from the parent component that I can modify in which there is a save button that when I click allows me to send the modified data to my beckend:

```
const handleConfirm = () => {
    axios.put(url, data).then((res) => {
      //Reload Component
    })
  }
```

I would like to be able to reload the parent component as soon as this works is successful what could I do? I don't want to reload the whole page I just want to reload the parent component that is "MyComponent", I hope I have well posed the problem.

Comment: Do you want to run the `fetchData` as well once reloaded, or no?

Comment: Yes I would like to recall it, I would like to find a way in which I can redo the "useEffect"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd pass the whole `useEffect` callback down so that `handleConfirm` can call it again after the `axios.put`, after which the `resData` state in the parent will be updated:

```
export default function MyComponent() {
    const url = "/api/1";
    const [resData, setResData] = useState(null);
    const tryLoginJWT = () => {
        const jwt = getJwt();
        const resP = await axios(url);
        setResData(resP.data);
    };
    useEffect(tryLoginJWT, []);

    return <EditComponent {...{ resData, tryLoginJWT }} />
}
```

```
const handleConfirm = () => {
    axios.put(url, data)
        .then(tryLoginJWT)
        .catch(handleErrors); // don't forget to catch here in case there's a problem
}
```

Comment: Taking a cue from your solution, I was able to solve thanks